# Read variables of a message that is sent by a server using socket

Tags: c#, sockets, listener, port

I am working on Passenger information system **PIS**(Train).So trains send their location to my server **PIS** using socket on port **8080** .So i should get their locations and show them to passengers . The message that comes from the trains has a template that i should follow that. As you can see here :

[image]

So as you can see here we have 6 variables .**every integer is 4 byte**. The first variable is(4 byte) **message source** and etc.

In my server i have to detect these variable but i don't know how can i detect them from the message .

```
 static void Listeners()
        {

            Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            if (socketForClient.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client:" + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " now connected to server.");
                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
                System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter =
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
                System.IO.StreamReader streamReader =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);

                while (true)
                {

                    TimeTableRepository objTimeTableRepository = new TimeTableRepository();
                    SensorRepository objSensorRepository = new SensorRepository();
                    ArrivalTimeRepository objArrivalTimeRepository=new ArrivalTimeRepository();
                    TrainRepository objTrainRepository = new TrainRepository();
                   // OnlineTrainRepository ObjOnlineTrainrepository = new OnlineTrainRepository();

                    //-----
                    string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();

                }
         }
}
```

Here is my **listener** to port 8080 and **theString** is the message that is send by trains.My problem is how can i detect this parameters (Message source,message destination and etc) from **theString**?I mean i need the value of them to store in database .

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't need to detect anything and definitely should **not** be slapping this in a string to try and parse.

You already know you are getting a bunch of integers back. You even know what order they are in. Use a [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get you your numbers and proceed from there. Once you load your reader up, it should be as simple as calling `BinaryReader.ReadInt32()` to read the message's numbers one after another.

I must also highly recommend you to look into `using` statements for your streams.

```
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream))
{
    var messageSource = reader.ReadInt32();
    var messageDestination = reader.ReadInt32();

    ... and so on ...
}
```

Comment: @EA Done. There is also an example on the link I provided to MSDN's doc.

Comment: Just one question ,my length of integer is static  .should i use this :pos += sizeof(int);

Comment: @EA No. The `BinaryReader` should be handling that for you already. Every time you call `ReadInt32()` it will automatically move it 4 bytes because that is the size of 32-bit integer. You should not have to manually move unless you need to skip `x` number of bytes.

Comment: i have a problem for reading binary data,if it's possible pease take a look :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448304/send-a-value-by-socket-and-read-the-value-by-reader-readint32